# Eclipse Tool Bar run button does not appear

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse luna toolbar only displays add file, breakpoint, and save buttons. There isn't anything else there. I tried to go to Perspective, Customize perspective, but there it says the launch group (run, debug) is already checked. Anyone help?

Comment: How about resetting the workspace ?

Comment: Is this your first time opening Eclipse?

Comment: Reset the Perspective and restart Eclipse Solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

Found this link on the eclipse luna documentation [Showing and hiding menu items and toolbar buttons](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm) have you tried the steps provided on that documentation?

If yes, then could you try to create a new workspace and see whether the toolbar button is visible or not. This problem also happened to me once and creating a new workspace seems fixed it.

hope that help

Comment: removing  .metadata from workspace works also, but you'll lose configurations for workspace if you have important configuration and you'll need to import projects back. so we can fix issue with making some edit in .metada , but currently i dont know what to edit becuase i already removed ^^.